# Junit returning an error on assertTrue string comparison

Tags: java, junit

```
     StringWriter result = runMethod.getOutput();
   String expected = "<3>textValue</3>"
    assertTrue("Should have contained the required result", result.toString().contains(expected));
```

Why does Junit return an error here ?

Comment: What does System.out.println(result.toString()) give you?

Comment: A big block of text and the expected string is contained within it.

Comment: When I print out System.out.println(result.toString().contains) prints a "true"

Comment: What is the error? Or does it just print the "Should have contained..."?

Comment: It says assertion error and prints out the "Should have contained ... "

Comment: I don't see any reason why assertion fails if `result` contains the searched string. However missing semicolon make me think that this is not the exact code you are running. Do you have anything else in this test case which can modify `result` or something like that?

Comment: This sounds silly, but are you sure you are actually using `assertTrue` and not `assertEquals` by mistake?  The latter should compile and would compare the message string to the boolean value, which is of course a failed assertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried this and it works fine.

It gives the following error if the string does not match.
java.lang.AssertionError: Should have contained the required result

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.io.StringWriter;

import org.junit.Test;

public class XYZ
{

    @Test
    public void test()
    {

        StringWriter result = new StringWriter();
        result.append("<3>textValue</3>");
        String expected = "<3>textValue</3>";
        assertTrue("Should have contained the required result", result.toString().contains(expected));
    }

}
```